# How to subdivide column name into two new columns in next line using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read the excel input file to convert into pandas data-frame format as below.
It has three columns [OFFICE NO, DAY HOURS, DAY RATES ] with two rows of values [(101, 8 , 60) , [102, 8, 60)]
Input:

```
OFFICE NO  DAY HOURS    DAY RATES
101        8            60
102        8            60
```

My final output in text file requires just two columns on first line [OFFICE NO, DAY JOB].  2nd line would require two divided [HOURS , RATES] columns beneath of "DAY JOB" main column name.
Output:

```
OFFICE NO  DAY JOB
          HOURS RATES 
101       8     60
102       8     60
```

Can you please guide me how to define columns in pandas in two different lines to achieve above output?.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there the expected output in text form (with correct formatting)?

Comment: You cannot have a split column in excel or pandas. If you want to separate hours and rates under one column, you must have two columns

Comment: @AndrejKesely Kesely - Sorry Andrej. I tried to put the dataframe-layout in question at first, however, it's converted all dataframe values in a single line rather than displaying in same tabular format. I am new member so couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Rav Use `Ctrl`+`K` for formatting.

Comment: @SimonNasser - Thanks for response.  I am looking for information if it's possible to define a columns HOURS , RATES  that must appear in a 2nd line.  Moreover, these two columns needs to be under the 1st line column 'DAY JOB'. 
Please advise if you have any information on this.

Comment: @AndrejKesely - Thank you. I have updated my question with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [pandas.MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples) might be what you are looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'OFFICE NO': [101, 102],
    'DAY HOURS': [8, 8],
    'DAY RATES': [60, 60]})
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('DAY JOB', 'HOURS'), ('DAY JOB', 'RATES')])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[['DAY HOURS', 'DAY RATES']].values, columns=columns, index=df['OFFICE NO'])
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
          DAY JOB      
            HOURS RATES
OFFICE NO              
101             8    60
102             8    60
```

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Bill. 
I am just wondering is it possible to have OFFICE NO and HOURS RATES on same line instead of different line ?.  Please advise if you have any inputs on this.

Comment: Note that the above output is simply the representation of the database when you print it to the console. The dataframe itself is not arranged in this way. The only way I know to print the index name and column names on the same line, is to use `reset_index` to make the index into a column.